# Can we delete a API in AWS API Gateway? If yes then how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I was exploring AWS API Gateway and created several APIs during learning session. Can I delete these API?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the AWS CLI by passing the API ID delete-rest-api:

```
aws apigateway delete-rest-api --rest-api-id 1234123412
```

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/delete-rest-api.html

Comment: Your approach may be right but i have found a easier way to delete an api. Actions dropdown has a delete option for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Delete API" action on Resources tab, Actions menu.

[image]